# the \b flag not working in JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regular expressions and basically just playing around with them in my brower console,  using MDN as a referance, I tried the below regex:

```
/\bg/g.test('me building and him')
```

even if I try `/\bg/g` , I still get false, WHY?

The MDN definition says the following for `\b`:

> Matches a zero-width word boundary, such as between a letter and a
>   space. (Not to be confused with [\b])
>
> For example, /\bno/ matches the "no" in "at noon"; /ly\b/ matches the
>   "ly" in "possibly yesterday".

So why is the `g` at the end of building not being matched?, can anybody explain?

Comment: Don't -1 the guy, people.. It's monday..

Comment: **For example, /\bno/ matches the "no" in "at noon"; /ly\b/ matches the "ly" in "possibly yesterday".** << Your answer is here.

Answer (score 5):

```
/\bg/g.test('me building and him')
```

`\bg/g` will try to search `g` after word boundary. The passed string does not contain any word starting with `g`.

[What is word-boundary?](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

I think you need

```
/g\b/.test('me building and him') // true: finds building
```

When using [`Regex#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), you don't need `g` flag/modifier.

Comment: @ShanShan 5 are for the explanation of what OP didn't see in the documentation :)

Comment: He quoted the doc on the exact spot (with very clear examples), he just didn't took the time to read it.

Comment: @ShanShan I think, the doc reference is blindly added, just to show the search efforts

Comment: Maybe but we shouldn't reward such lazyness then? Worst part is it took him more time to write a question and read your answer than just read the two sentences doc quote. Anyway, helping people to read seems to rep more than bother with real issues xD